# How line of sight is determined?

Tags: astronomy, stars, binary-stars

How do they calculate the line of sight of a galaxy or binary star system from an observer's point of view. the velocity of a star in a binary star system depends on the line of sight so how do they measure that crucial parameter with precise values?

> but in case of unresolvable binary star system like spectrometric and astrometric binaries how do they take the (sin i) parameter

Answer (score 0):

> How do they calculate the line of sight of a galaxy or binary star system from an observer's point of view ?

"Line of sight" simply means "in the direction of the observed object". By comparing the observed spectrum of a galaxy against its expected spectrum, we can determine the amount of [Doppler shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doppler_effect) in the light that reaches us. This in turn lets us calculate the component of the velocity of the galaxy along its line of sight. The other component of its velocity - perpendicular to its line of sight - is more difficult to determine. But for distant galaxies the line of sight component of velocity is larger and more interesting (because of the [expansion of the universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expansion_of_the_universe)).

Answer (score 0):

For a binary to be detectable in the first place requires that it be close enough to us that the line of sight can be taken to be a straight line (i.e., no lensing effects from intervening mass concentrations).

Comment: but in case of unresolvable binary star system like spectrometric and astrometric binaries how do they take the (sin i) parameter

Comment: I do not know. -NN

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your comment to another answer (which I've added to the question, since I think it clarifies matters), you want to know how the $\sin i$ parameter is estimated - the sine of the inclination of an orbit to the line of sight This is an important parameter since the observed radial velocity amplitude of a binary or the observer radial velocity for a circular orbit in a galaxy is $v \sin i$, where $v$ is the actual speed.

For a spiral galaxy then $\sin i$ can be estimated by just looking at the shape, assuming that the galaxy is a circular disk viewed from an angle, and hence that the ratio of the shortest observed diameter to the longest diameter is roughly $1 - \sin i$, where $i$ is defined as 90 degrees if the orbital axis is at 90 degrees to the line of sight.

For an unresolved binary star system it is harder. If the binary is eclipsing then we know that $\sin i \sim 1$ and detailed modelling of the eclipse light curve can give an accurate value for $\sin i$.

If the binary is not eclipsing then another possibility is to model the ellipsoidal modulation caused by the tidal forces between the two components. The tidal forces distort the stars according to the [Roche potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roche_lobe) and as they orbit each other, this means the stellar area that is seen as a function of orbital phase varies, and then so does the light received from the binary. Modelling this ellipsoidal modulation can give the mass ratio of the binary and $\sin i$. This only works for relatively short period and compact binary systems where tidal forces are strong.

Another method that works in binary systems with orbital periods less than about 7 days is to assume they are tidally locked with rotation periods equal to their orbital periods. By measuring the broadening of one of the star's spectral lines we get a value for $v_{\rm eq} \sin i$ where $v_{\rm eq}$ is the equatorial velocity of the star. If the radius of the star can be estimated from its spectral type, then $v_{\rm eq} \simeq 2\pi R/P$, where $P$ is the orbital/rotational period and hence $\sin i \simeq P(v_{\rm eq}\sin i)/2\pi R$.

If the binary is resolved, then the elliptical orbit can be modelled with $\sin i$ as a free parameter. If $i>0$ then the focus of the apparent ellipse of one star around the other on the sky will be displaced from the position of that other star. However, Kepler's first law states that one of the stars should be at the real focus, so this displacement is a consequence of the projection of the orbit onto the plane of the sky and is sensitive to $\sin i$.